# Get data into array using mysql prepared statements

Tags: mysql, arrays, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get the function below to return an array of user_ids. Here is the function in php.

```
 function users_following($follower_id)
        {
            include "dbconn.php";

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT user_id FROM follo WHERE follower_id = ?");

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $follower_id); 

            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $following_user_id);

            $count = 0;
            $user_array = array();

            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) ) {
                $user_array[] = $following_user_id;
                $count = $count + 1;
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

            if ($count > 0) 
            {
                return $user_array;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

The problem is that the above function just returns the output: 'Array' (without quotes), when I tested with the code below, not the list of user_ids.

```
$userid_array = users_following($_SESSION["user_id"]);

echo $userid_array;
```

Can anyone please help me out? If you need additional details, just comment below and I will try to clarify.

Comment: I tried your code and I get: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php`. As I thought, you cannot display an array with `echo`. If you want to see the output for your debugging, try either `var_dump($userid_array)` or `echo implode(",", $userid_array);` (`implode` will convert your array in a comma separated string).

Comment: Thanks, I used echo implode(",", $userid_array); based on your suggestion and it works.